# Cannot switch to GUI mode

Tags: boot

I found my old laptop yesterday and it is running Ubuntu 12.10. I opened it, but there was just a black screen with a blinking underscore. I restarted again and pressed F12, clicked HDD and found Ubuntu.

I clicked it and typed in root and my password. To mention, it was in CLI mode. I tried ways to go to GUI mode, but couldn't. I ran:

```
startx
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

and

```
sudo apt-get update
```

but they all showed an error. I tried `alt+F7` but it showed the blinking underscore again.

If you find a way to fix it, please help me as I really want to use my old laptop. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.10 is way beyond end of life ....

Answer (score 0):

First try and upgrade Ubuntu to the latest version by running the following command:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

and then we update everything else:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now reinstall the Ubuntu Desktop:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```